# How take Backup of 2 database into 1 .sql file in mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-workbench

````
FOR /D %%F IN (*) DO (

IF [%%F]==[performance_schema]  (
SET %%F=!%%F:@002d=-!
%mysqldumpexe% --user=%dbuser% --password=%dbpass% --port=3306 --databases --routines --log-error=%errorLogPath% %%F > "%backupfldr%%%F.%backuptime%.sql"
) ELSE (
echo Skipping DB backup for performance_schema
)
)
```
````

This is my batch file

it takes backup of 1 db, how to alter it to take backup of 2 db into 1 .sql file
it would be helpful if anyone know answer
Thank you.

Comment: You do know you can append to an output file by doing `command >> outputfile.sql`, right? Use `>>` instead of `>` to redirect stdout and you'll append to the file instead of creating a new one.

Comment: I'd question why it would be helpful to have two DBs in one file - then it's more difficult to restore them separately if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the mysqldump command adding the databases that you want to backup as a parameter of the --databases option, something like this:

```
$ mysqldump -udbuser -pdbpass --databases db1 db2 > backupName.sql
```